# Grails UrlMapping works for view but not action

Tags: grails

I am trying to map a specific section to a controller action so can return some text.

It seems like I should do this:

```
"500"(exception: MaxUploadSizeExceededException, controller: "error", action: "max_upload_size_exceeded")
```

but it does not work.

Strangely though this does work:

```
"500"(exception: MaxUploadSizeExceededException, view:'/error/error.404')
```

Any suggestions on why one may work and not the other? Note we are stuck on an old version of grails (1.3.9).

controller action for reference:

```
def max_upload_size_exceeded= {
    render(view: "/error/error.404", model: [:])
}
```

Comment: "but it does not work." - In what way does it not work?  Is the action being invoked but the view cannot be found?  Can the action not be found?  Something else?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It doesn't hit the action. It just uses the default server error